# Tensorflow read large file line by line

Tags: python, tensorflow

Please see the following code:

```
x = np.loadtxt(path + 'x.csv', delimiter=",")
x = x / np.max(x,axis=1, keepdims=True)

y = np.loadtxt(path + 'y.csv', delimiter=",")
y = y  / 255.0


ip_shape = x.shape[1]
n = y.shape[1]


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(ip_shape)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(n,  activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(n,  activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(n,  activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid)
    ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(x,y, batch_size = 32, epochs=100)
```

Note that here x.csv and y.csv are large, and it's getting trouble loading the entire file in memory. But my batch size is only 32. My question is, what is the best way to handle this situation?

Can I pass a file instead of a tensor to model.fit? If not, how I can instruct model.fit to read line by line from the file and process it?

N.B. Can this be enhanced to a directory structure, also? That is, if there are multiple files in a directory, can I instruct model.fit to load them batch by batch and process them?

My anticipation:
It must be true. There must be a wayout.

Comment: Use a proper [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) for streaming dataset to avoid loading dataset all at once into the memory. In particular, you may want to take a look at [`tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/CsvDataset).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`make_csv_dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/make_csv_dataset) to load data lazily:

```
x = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    'x.txt',
    batch_size=32,
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=True,
    shuffle_seed=2023,
    ignore_errors=True,)

y = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    'y.txt',
    batch_size=32,
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=True,
    shuffle_seed=2023,
    ignore_errors=True,)
```

Comment: But its in experimental.

Comment: I think it's not really a problem. Another solution is to create your own [`Sequence`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence)

Comment: Okk but how to integrate with 'lazy execution'. I replaced x = np.loadtxt(path + 'x.csv', delimiter=",")
x = x / np.max(x,axis=1, keepdims=True)

y = np.loadtxt(path + 'y.csv', delimiter=",")
y = y  / 255.0 with your code but its not working.